# Referring path variable in jsp Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I pass couple of objects "Studentdetails" and String-"dept" to JSP.

Question-

How will I refer studentdetail.st.fname in my JSP file? ie; need to refer the firstname from the Student object.

I tried this and its failing -

```
<form:label path="s.studentdetail.st.fname" class="labels">First Name</form:label>
AND 
<form:label path="studentdetail.st.fname" class="labels">First Name</form:label>



   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       model.put("studentdetail", new Studentdetails());
       model.put("department", "dept");
       return new ModelAndView("student", "s", model);
  }
```

Studentdetails:

```
public class Studentdetails {
    public ContactInfo getCi() {
        return ci;
    }
    public void setCi(ContactInfo ci) {
        this.ci = ci;
    }
    public Student getSt() {
        return st;
    }
    public void setSt(Student st) {
        this.st = st;
    }
    ContactInfo ci;
    Student st;
}
```

Student:

```
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String fname;
    private String mname;
    private String lname;
    private String dob;
    private String gender;
    private String birthplace;
    private String nationality;
    private String mothertongue;
    private String religion;
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }

    public void setMname(String mname) {
        this.mname = mname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getBirthplace() {
        return birthplace;
    }

    public void setBirthplace(String birthplace) {
        this.birthplace = birthplace;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getMothertongue() {
        return mothertongue;
    }

    public void setMothertongue(String mothertongue) {
        this.mothertongue = mothertongue;
    }

    public String getReligion() {
        return religion;
    }

    public void setReligion(String religion) {
        this.religion = religion;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

COntactinfo

```
public class ContactInfo {
    String addr1;
    String addr2;
    String city;
    String state;
    String pin;
    String country;
    String phone;
    String mobile;
    String email;
    public String getAddr1() {
        return addr1;
    }
    public void setAddr1(String addr1) {
        this.addr1 = addr1;
    }
    public String getAddr2() {
        return addr2;
    }
    public void setAddr2(String addr2) {
        this.addr2 = addr2;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }
    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Working code:---

```
<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/SpringMVC/addStudent" modelAttribute="studentdetail">

    <br><br>
    <form:label path="st.fname" class="labels">First Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="st.fname" class="textbox" />

    <br><br>
    studentdetail:${studentdetail.st.fname}
    <br>
    Department:${department}
    <br><br>

</form>
```

Controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       model.put("studentdetail", new Studentdetails());
       model.put("department", "dept");
       return new ModelAndView("student",model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<form:label path="s['studentdetail'].st.fname" class="labels">First Name</form:label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array of Studentdetails then you have to use that array on your form declaration on the modelAndAttribute field, and then using a foreach to iterate everyone, and using the index.

```
     <form:form
            id=""
            method="post"
           action=""
            modelAttribute="studentdetail">


    <form:input type="text"   id=""
        path="studentdetail.st.fname"/>

    </form:form>
```

Comment: there is no StudentDetails array in question. there is StudentDetail bean added in model.

Comment: I have given the working code above..Question:--The FORM works only if the modelattribute="studentdetail" is given..I was able to access the "department" attribute directly

Comment: you can always can access to your render parameters with ${value} but if you want to use components form only the modelAndAttribute entity can be accesed

Answer (score 0):

First your construction of a `ModelAndView` is at least uncommon. You add an unnecessary level of indirection by putting in string model an only attribute `s` that contains the real model. In JSP you should have to use `${s["studentdetail"].st.fname}` ... if you had initialized `studentdetail.st` ...

IMHO, you'd better change your method to :

```
public ModelAndView student() {
   Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   Studentdetails studentdetail = new Studentdetails());
   studentdetail = new Studentdetails());
   studentdetail.setSt(new Student()); //put a Student in studentdetail
   model.put("studentdetail", studentdetail);
   model.put("department", "dept");
   return new ModelAndView("student", model); // directly use model in ModelAndView
```

}

Then in the JSP, you simply use `${studentdetail.st.fname}`

Comment: Thanks, I have given the working code with Spring form path variable...The studentdetail works only if the modelattirbute is given